# Профайлер не находит отладочные символы

Tags: visual-c++, profiler

Пытаюсь профилировать .dll под visual studio 2019. В результатах профайлера не вижу имен функций:

```
Function Name   Total CPU [unit, %] Self CPU [unit, %]  Module  Category
 + caller.exe (PID: 4016)   2013 (100.00 %) 0 (0.00 %)  Multiple modules    
| + [External Code] 1999 (99.30 %)  12 (0.60 %) Multiple modules    IO | Networking | File System | Kernel
|| + membrane.dll!0x0007fecb031a6d  1983 (98.51 %)  0 (0.00 %)  membrane.dll    IO | Networking | File System | Kernel
||| - membrane.dll!0x0007fecaf88956 1971 (97.91 %)  0 (0.00 %)  membrane.dll    IO | Networking | Kernel
||| - membrane.dll!0x0007fecaf88770 7 (0.35 %)  0 (0.00 %)  membrane.dll    File System | Kernel
||| - membrane.dll!0x0007fecaf88615 1 (0.05 %)  0 (0.00 %)  membrane.dll    Kernel
||| - membrane.dll!0x0007fecaf887b9 1 (0.05 %)  0 (0.00 %)  membrane.dll    Networking
...
```

В окне output / Diagnostics Hub вижу:

```
Profiling of 'membrane' started.
membrane has exited.
Profiling of 'membrane' stopped.
Symbols loaded for ntdll.dll from C:\Users\chorkov\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\ntdll.pdb\abc4620307ca4364a82456c8c70e18121\ntdll.pdb
Symbols failed to load for membrane.dll.
Symbols failed to load for mkl_core.dll.
Symbols loaded for ucrtbase.dll from C:\Users\chorkov\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\ucrtbase.pdb\c3dd2c823498457082399db3ec47fbac1\ucrtbase.pdb
Symbols failed to load for mkl_rt.dll.
Symbols failed to load for mkl_sequential.dll.
Symbols loaded for vcruntime140.dll from C:\Users\chorkov\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\vcruntime140.amd64.pdb\535e869d669a4c26b1e617d5dc794fcd1\vcruntime140.amd64.pdb
Symbols loaded for msvcp140.dll from C:\Users\chorkov\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache\msvcp140.amd64.pdb\95bf7f2825564665ba6dca0bd2cfd8ff1\msvcp140.amd64.pdb
Symbol lookup progress: 10 / 37
Symbols failed to load for hal.dll. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Symbols loaded for caller.exe from D:\WB\_svn\cwb4\make\output\cwb\bin\caller.pdb
```

Т.е. для membrane.dll он не смог загрузить отладочные символы, хотя файл membrane.pdb существует (лежит рядом с .dll). Отладчик - нормально автоматически подгружает символы и позволяет ходить по исходному коду membrane.dll. Аналогичный .pdb для вызывающего приложения (caller.exe) загружается профайлером нормально.

Какие логи еще существуют, и как определить почему символы не грузятся?